# How to get complete content from html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a sybex website https://sybextestbanks.wiley.com/public/index/login?page=register to view flashcards. The site shows one flash card at a time for a total of 100 cards. I would like to get the text for all the flash cards so I can create a document of all the flash card questions, instead of copying and pasting from each individual flash card. Is there a way to find the source for the flashcard material?
Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Use jQuery's `.html()`

Comment: Please consider to choose the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

press function f12 on your keyboard to access the developer console.

Comment: I'm not sure what to search for on the source page

Comment: Search for the flash cards that you want to copy the html from.

Comment: there is a box in the top left of dev console (firefox and chrome) select this and hover over the title and it should show you the element.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you right click and check the "View page source"?

Comment: I did, and I see a lot of html, but how do I find the tag that will show me the  link to the flashcard content

Comment: will control+f (search on the page) help you?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: <link href="Css/Css.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

Comment: so im not sure which one i need